# Terminal Server 2003 Gaining Time when Windows 7 Client Connects

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, terminal-server, time-synchronization

A Windows 2003 Terminal Server keeps time perfectly until a Windows 7 Home client connects. Then it gains time at a rate of several seconds per minute. The client connects through a firewall with only the RDP port open. The client runs the same apps on the terminal server that XP clients run with no issues. Using the Microsoft Terminal Server Client application copied to the W7 computer from an XPsp3 computer gives the same results. Current workaround is to sync time every 5 minutes. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the real problem was actually an application the user managed to run from the terminal server - TOR to bypass our web filtering. After putting a stop to this application the problem seems to have gone away.
After the problem came back it appears the real problem was Java. Some web sites have Java applications that cause the Windows time to speed up. After disabling Java in the web browser the problem has gone away.

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

If this hasn't already been solved you may like to restrict the permissions on the server so that users cannot adjust the time on the server. That won't get rid of the root cause, for which I have no suggestion, but should at least prevent this odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In my case the users are running as normal users so they are already unable to adjust the time on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the time in the RDP session is accelerating or that the time on the server console is accelerating? Are you using Time Zone redirection in the RDP session?

Comment: Good questions! The time on the server console is accelerating which affects every RDP session on the server, not just the one Windows 7 session. We are not using Time Zone redirection.

Comment: OK, then I have no idea. That's a strange one. If I find anything I'll post it here.

Comment: Wow, that's a really odd one. What applications are you running on the TS? I regularly connect from my W7 Laptop to various TS servers (2003, 2003R2, 2008, and 2008R2) and have never seen anything like this.

Comment: Our main application is written by a local company with only a few hundred customers. The application is written mostly in Java. I narrowed it down to the Windows 7 client because this client connects only on certain days of the week and only to 1 of our 2 terminal servers. (We are not using load balancing, we just assign certain users to one or the other terminal server.) We only see the time acceleration on those days of the week and that particular terminal server.